# Changing tab order in editor window of Intelli-J IDEA

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Does anyone know whether it is possible to change the tab order that tabs are displayed in the Intelli-J IDEA?

Sometimes it is handy to have two specific tab together so that it is easier to switch between them using either the mouse or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> respectively.  If the two tabs are together it reduces the keystrokes required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag & drop tabs since IDEA 8.1.x version. Try [8.1.4](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/IDEADEV/Diana+EAP) from EAP. If your IDEA version doesn't support it, use the [TabReorder plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=187).

Comment: Great thanks! I have version 8.1 and note from the above link that version 1.4 of the plug-in does what I need:

"Version 1.4
- IDEA 8.1 support (note that IDEA 8.1 has built-in tab reorder support if "Show tabs in single row" is checked in the "settings/editor/editor tabs")"

Plus I can get support without the plugin by choosing the above option.  Thanks!

Comment: For IDEA Ultimate 9.0, you need to do the same i.e. check "Show tabs in single row" in "settings/editor/editor tabs".